# Calculating point on edge of circle

Tags: c++, math, vector, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Using C++ I tried to calculate coordinates of point X(on edge of the circle) using point J and O

But I don't really know how to do it mathematically and I would appreciate some help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a question about C++ per se, and even the question seems incomplete from a mathematical point of view. You need the radius of the circle, and the point J has no relation whatsoever with the radius.

Comment: Do you have any C++ code that you have already tried? Attempt to solve the problem yourself first, and then if you get stuck, post what code you have so far, and others here would be happy to help you.

Comment: I don't feel like we have enough info to solve the problem. You mention points J and O, but your picture is showing a lot more. Do we know R? Where on the edge are we trying to find the coordinates? The bottom? Do we have an angle? Also, what is J representing exactly?

Comment: Yes, we know r value coordinates of J, O black and red points except the X point. J is the point on line right under O. The circle is an object between black point(player) and red point(enemy). I want to calculate how to reach enemy moving around the collision object - through X coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute X as follows, where R is the radius of the circle.

```
X = O + R * normalize(J - O)
```